# How can I use double as a function parameters without losing precision?

Tags: java, double, precision, latitude-longitude

I have the following function, and I cannot change the `double` type of the parameters.

```
double latitude = coordinate.x;
double longitude = coordinate.y;
createEPoint(latitude, longitude));
```

The vars latitude and longitude have a large number of decimals (35.94777225005756), and I need to keep its precision. I know that I could use [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) or other classes but as I said I cannot modify the parameters of `createEPoint(double lat, double lon)`.

By now when I get the parameters of EPoint the value of the latitude and longitude are rounded automatically, do you have any ideas to avoid that and keep the precision of the numbers?

Comment: Well, if double loses precision then you cannot do much about that besides changing the type of the parameters.

Comment: That's when the @Deprecated annotation comes in handy. So consider overloading your method.

Comment: If you must accept doubles, then it's already too late. There's no magic way to get more precision from a double than it had when it came in.

Comment: What are the types of `x` and `y` ?

Comment: Rounded? What do you mean by that? If you print them they'll be rounded/truncated, but otherwise not if you don't do that in your code.

Comment: x and y are double too.

Comment: Where do your higher precision values come from? And why can't you change the type of the parameters? Are you calling that method or implementing it?

Comment: Remember that when you print a `double` it will be truncated during printing by default. This does not indicate that the actual value is truncated/rounded. Try printing it with more decimal places to confirm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest double to 35.94777225005756 has exact value 35.94777225005756093878517276607453823089599609375 and its Double.toString result, the default printout, is 35.94777225005756.

There is inherent loss of precision in the conversion from your decimal number to double, and nothing can recover that. You would have to store and carry around a second representation of the point, using BigDecimal coordinates.

However, it is very unlikely that any physical location has ever been measured to one part in 1e15, the approximate precision of the decimal - double - decimal conversion. If, as suggested by the variable names, this is an angle in degrees to a location on a sphere of circumference 40,075 kilometers, the precision loss is much smaller than a micron.